# Array displays only the last data in my array and not the whole data

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I want to loop the **this.results** and add display the data in v-calendar but as of now it just displays the last element and not the whole data of my JSON.

Here's my template

```
<v-calendar
  type="month"
  now="2019-01-08"
  value="2019-01-08"
  :events="events"
></v-calendar>
```

and here's my script.

**NOTE**: **this.results** is a JSON and **this.events** is just an array

```
this.results.forEach(element => {
    this.events = [
      {
        name: element.name,
        details: element.details,
        start: element.start,
        end: element.end,
        color: "black"
      }
    ];
    console.log(element);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `push` items in `this.events` array:-

```
this.results.forEach(element => {
    this.events.push({
        name: element.name,
        details: element.details,
        start: element.start,
        end: element.end,
        color: "black"
      });
    console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `map` method, or `forEach` method + `push` method.

```
this.events = this.results.map(function(element) {
  return {
    name: element.name,
    details: element.details,
    start: element.start,
    end: element.end,
    color: "black"
  };
});
console.log(this, events);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` method of array to insert data in array. Currently, you are just assigning the value to `this.events` which is showing you last assigned value in it.

Here is code

```
this.results.forEach(element => {
    this.events.push(
      {
        name: element.name,
        details: element.details,
        start: element.start,
        end: element.end,
        color: "black"
      }
    );
    console.log(element);
  });
```